# what is the syntactic function of the underlined clause?

Tags: syntax

what is the syntactic function of the underlined clause in the following sentence:

> Based on the interview, it was found **THAT ALL OF THE STUDENTS TRANSFERRED ENGLISH INTO INDONESIAN LANGUAGE** when they read the sentence.

Comment: Many verbs relating to thought or feeling take a that-clause as an object, for example "I know **that he is lying**". What makes you think that this sentence might not be a simple that-clause?

Comment: There is nothing that is underlined in the question. Just shouting in capitals.

Comment: Also, "*...when they read the sentence" is part of the highlighted "that" clause. The portion you highlighted isn't a unit that can have a syntactic function without the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's not a complete clause, because *when they read the sentence* is part of it.

Secondly, it's not grammatical because it needs an article *the* before *Indonesian language*. ("into Indonesian" would be fine, but with "language" it needs the article).

Thirdly, in answer to your question, the entire "that" clause is the syntactic complement, but the logical subject, of the passive verb  *was found*.

Comment: Wouldn't you consider it an example of extraposition?

Comment: Yes, now I've read about _it_-extraposition. I was only aware of heavy clause extraposition. I'm not convinced that it's useful to use the same term for a rather different process.

Answer (score 0):

> *... it was found* [*that all students transferred*
> *English into Indonesian language*...]

This is an extraposition construction, with the dummy pronoun "it" as subject and the bracketed subordinate content clause as extraposed subject at the end.

But that doesn't mean the subordinate clause is a kind of subject; it's an element in extraposed position, outside the verb phrase, that corresponds to the subject of the basic non-extraposed version.

Comment: In this case, there is no basic (non-extraposed) equivalent: _[That all students transferred English into Indonesian language] was found ..._ is ungrammatical.

Comment: Yes, but why is it ungrammatical? is it the passive verb? I'm inclining to the view that _find that_ is a different lexical item from _find_.